# Have to wait for the second file upload request for the first one's data to send to AWS S3

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload

Any help is greatly appreciated! I've spent so long searching but I haven't found a solution or a problem like mine...

I'm writing an Electron application, and as part of it, there is a section for the users to drag and drop files. I'm then taking that file and uploading it to AWS S3.

The first time I drag and drop it goes into my function but no request is sent out to AWS S3, I then drag and drop again and it sends out the expected request and saves the file however it's the first requests information (name, path & body), and from then on when I drag and drop the file it send outs the request every time but always with the previous request's info. It's like its one sequence behind....

This is the s3 code:

```
function submitNewFileS3(file, filepath) {
   const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

   AWS.config = new AWS.Config({
       accessKeyId: localStorage.getItem("accessKeyId"),
       secretAccessKey: localStorage.getItem("secretAccessKey"),
       region: 'eu-west-2'
   });

   var upload = new AWS.S3.ManagedUpload({
      params: {
          Bucket: 'sampe-bucket',
          Key: filepath, // File name you want to save as in S3
          Body: file
      }
   });
   return upload.promise();
}
```

How I call the function:

```
   var reader = new FileReader();

   reader.onload = function (e2) {
           // finished reading file data.
           finishUploading(e2.target.result);
    }

    function finishUploading(url) {

            // strip off the data: url prefix to get just the base64-encoded bytes
            var data;

            if (url.indexOf('data:image') > -1) {
                data = url.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, "");
            } else if (url.indexOf('data:application') > -1) {
                data = url.replace(/^data:application\/\w+;base64,/, "");
            }

             //only firing after sencon upload

            var buf = Buffer.from(data, 'base64');

            var filePathS3 = directory + (fileName).replace(/\-/g, "_").replace(/ /g, "_");
            submitNewFileS3(buf, filePathS3).then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            }).catch(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            });
     }

     reader.readAsDataURL(f); // start reading the file data.
```

Does anyone have any suggestions - I'm going out of my mind...I've tried so many tutorials and solutions and they all work...on the second call...

I've double checked all the required data is ready before making the request.

Many thanks in advance!

EDIT - more of what's going on in my main before sending my file to be uploaded:

```
function handleDrop(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    var directory;

    if (e.target.id == 'drop_zone_overview') {
        //placed in general area, check which folders are showing to get dir
        console.log(e);

        //get whats visible
        var whatPath;
        $(".icon").each(function () {
           if (this.style.display != 'none') {
               whatPath = this.id;
           }
        });
        //pick one and check what root we're in
        var pathArray = whatPath.split('-');
        console.log(pathArray);

    } else if (e.target.id == 'drop_zone_individual') {
       //placed on top of folder, check dir
       directory = (e.target).getAttribute('data-targetfolder');
       console.log(directory);
    }

    var files = e.dataTransfer.files,
        folder;

    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) { // iterate in the files dropped
        if (!f.type && f.size % 4096 == 0) {
            // The file is a folder
            folder = true;
        } else {
            // The file is not a folder
            folder = false;
        }

        const fs = require('fs');

        console.log(f);

        var fileName = f.name;

        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e2) {
            // finished reading file data.
            finishUploading(e2.target.result);
        }

        function finishUploading(url) {
            // strip off the data: url prefix to get just the base64-encoded bytes
            var data;

            if (url.indexOf('data:image') > -1) {
                data = url.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, "");
            } else if (url.indexOf('data:application') > -1) {
                data = url.replace(/^data:application\/\w+;base64,/, "");
            }

            var buf = Buffer.from(data, 'base64');

            var filePathS3 = directory + (fileName).replace(/\-/g, "_").replace(/ /g, "_");
            submitNewFileS3(buf, filePathS3).then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            }).catch(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            });

        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(f); // start reading the file data.

        uploadedFiles.push(f);
    }


    uploadedFiles.forEach(function (file) {
        var pathKey = directory + (file.name).replace(/\-/g, "_");
        pathKey = pathKey.replace(/ /g, "_").replace(/\//g, '-').replace(/\./g, '__');

        if ($('#' + pathKey).length) {
            //filename already exists in directory
            alert(file.name + ' already exists in folder ' + directory);
        } else {
            var displayDiv;

            if (file.type == 'image/png') {
                //image
                //add to directory
                displayDiv = '<img id="' + pathKey + '" class="fileInfo thumb file-type file-type-img" src="' + URL.createObjectURL(file) + '" ondblclick="preview_image(this)"/>'

            } else if (file.type == 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet') {
                //xlsx doc
                displayDiv = '<div id="' + pathKey + '" class="fileInfo thumb file-type file-type-xlsx" data-downloadLink="' + URL.createObjectURL(file) + '" ></div>';

            } else if (file.type == 'application/pdf') {
                //pdf doc
                displayDiv = '<div id="' + pathKey + '" class="fileInfo thumb file-type file-type-pdf" data-downloadLink="' + URL.createObjectURL(file) + '" ></div>';

            } else if (file.type == 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document') {
                 //word doc
                displayDiv = '<div id="' + pathKey + '" class="fileInfo thumb file-type file-type-docx" data-downloadLink="' + URL.createObjectURL(file) + '" </div>';

                console.log('its a doc');

             } else if (file.type == 'application/x-zip-compressed') {
               //zip file doc

               displayDiv = '<div id="' + pathKey + '" class="fileInfo thumb file-type file-type-zip" data-downloadLink="' + URL.createObjectURL(file) + '" </div>';
           } else if (file.type == '') {
               //folder 
               console.log('what typep  is this~~~~~    ' + file.type);
               file.name = file.name + '/';
           }

           //save to folder array

            if (file.type == 'application/x-zip-compressed' || file.type == '') {
               var htmlTemplate = [
                   getHtml([
                    '<li id=' + pathKey.replace(/ /g, "_").replace(/\//g, '-').replace(/\./g, '__') + ' class="icon folderItems fileInfo thumb"  data-downloadLink="directory_' + pathKey + '" ondblclick="viewAlbum(this.id)" style="display:none">',
                    '<i id="drop_zone_individual" data-targetFolder="' + pathKey + '" class="folders fas fa-folder" style="font-size: 115px; color: rgb(13, 36, 60); cursor: pointer;"></i>',
                    '<div class="folderLabel" style="text-align:center">' + file.name + '</div>',
                    '</li>'
                    ])
                ];

                folders.push({
                    Key: directory + (file.name).replace(/\-/g, "_").replace(/ /g, "_"),
                    LastModified: file.lastModifiedDate,
                   Size: file.size,
                });

            } else {

                //append to ui file list
                var htmlTemplate = [
                    getHtml([
                    '<li id=' + pathKey + ' class="icon downloadableItem" style="display:none">',
                    '<span>',
                    '<div style="text-align:center">',
                    displayDiv,
                    '</div>',
                    '<div style="text-align:center">',
                    '<span>',
                    file.name,
                    '</span>',
                    '</div>',
                    '</span>',
                    '</li>'
                   ])
                ];


                //save to folder list
                folders.push({
                    Key: directory + (file.name).replace(/\-/g, "_").replace(/ /g, "_"),
                    LastModified: file.lastModifiedDate,
                    Size: file.size,
                    signedUrl: URL.createObjectURL(file)
                });
            }

            localStorage.setItem("s3Objects", JSON.stringify(folders));

            $('#photoAlbumViewerList').append(htmlTemplate);

            console.log(folders);

            $("#" + pathKey).click(function (e) {
            getAlbumInfo(this.id);

                if (e.shiftKey) {
                    if ($(this).hasClass('thumb')) {
                       $(this).removeClass('thumb').addClass('thumbChecked');
                       $(this).css("border", "2px solid #c32032");


                       // $(this).attr("data-downloadLink");
                       links.push($(this).attr("data-downloadLink"));

                       if (links.length != 0) {
                           $('.download').css("display", "block");
                       }
                   } else if ($(this).hasClass('thumbChecked')) {
                       $(this).removeClass('thumbChecked').addClass('thumb');
                       $(this).css("border", "2px solid white");
                       var itemtoRemove = $(this).attr('src');
                       links.splice($.inArray(itemtoRemove, links), 1);
                       console.log(links);

                       if (links.length == 0) {
                           $('.download').css("display", "none");
                       }
                    }
                }
            });
       }
   });

    uploadedFiles = [];
    e.target.classList.remove('drop_zone_hovered');
    $('#drop_zone_text').hide();
}
```

Comment: FYI Someone just came back informing me I hadn't returned the promise - Thank you to whom came back, I wish it was that silly! I've tried it and still no joy

Comment: Can you add more of your code around `submitNewFileS3`? Are you using a loop?

Comment: @eol that's literally it. I wanted to start off small to get it working and then build up the complexity. Once a file comes in I send the buffer of it and the path specified directly to submitNewFileS3 to upload it straight away.

Comment: @eol Nothing gets printed out, on both accounts it goes into the function, but on the first call it goes quiet, and there after it returns the expected result. Sometimes the second call returns both data from the first and second call. Try/catch returns nothing first time and success thereafter.

PS thank you for your help

Comment: Having `return await upload.promise().then(...)` is certainly not helping you. I would expect this to be `return upload.promise()` and the caller would either await or use `.then` on the thenable promise that you returned, but not both await/then.

Comment: Thank you @jarmod..as you can see I'm trying anything...Changed my code back and still the same issue

Comment: @S.Mac: Is your code on github or something similar so that I can check it in detail?

Comment: @eol: I'm afraid it's not open source so I can't share the program, I've edited my post to include the entire function to try give you as much information as I can, I hope this is enough!  I really appreciate all your help! (I've removed the fs.writefile to avoid confusion as it's not needed for the upload)

Comment: The code is a bit of a mess (no offense :)), try avoiding `var`s and use `let/const` instead - also you could try to upload one file only without looping or anything and see if this works. It will also help you to debug the issue.

Comment: None taken, in no way do I think this is gold standard :))  I'll try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an FYI - the issue lied where I reinitialised AWS and S3 variables, it wasn't needed as I set it at the start of launch and reinitialising it slowed it all down while it remade the connection!